# Python Dump YAML Using Double Quotes Around Strings

Tags: python, yaml, python-3.5, quotes, double-quotes

In Python 3.5, I have the following dictionary to be dumped into a .yaml file.

`D={'name': 'mydata', value: {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}}`

When I run the following code:

```
import ruamel
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
D={'name': 'mydata', 'value': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}}
yaml.round_trip_dump(D, open('my_yaml.yaml', 'w'),
                     default_flow_style=False, indent=4)
```

The resulting `my_yaml.yaml` looks like the following:

```
name: mydata                                                                    
value:                                                                     
    z: 3                                                                     
    x: 1                                                                   
    y: 2
```

My question is, is there a handy way to write double quotes around `mydata`, i.e., instead of `name: mydata`, it is written as `name: "mydata"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a relatively easy way to do this:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
D = {'name': S('mydata'), 'value': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3}}

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)
yaml.dump(D, sys.stdout)
```

that last three lines, using an instance of YAML, is the newer way of doing:

```
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(D, sys.stdout, indent=4)
```

Using the new API, you can give a different indent value for your sequences.

Either way, the above gives you:

```
name: "mydata"
value:
    x: 1
    y: 2
    z: 3
```

There is no need to explicitly do `default_flow_style=False` when using `ruamel.yaml`s round-trip-mode.

---

The `DoubleQuotedScalarString`, a subclass of `str`, is what is used to store `"mydata"` if you load your preferred output, while preserving quotes:

```
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load("""\
name: "mydata"
value:
    x: 1
    y: 2
    z: 3
""")
print(type(data['name']))
```

gives:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString'>
```

If your output round-trips correctly, it is always a good idea to inspect the data structure `ruamel.yaml` loads, whether it is for double quotes, block style literal scalars, hexadecimal ints or comment preservation.
The library does a lot behind the scenes for which there is no documentation, and the library's author is probably too lazy to provide more of it.