# Generate YAML file from python with certain keys and values with double quotes

Tags: python, yaml

Recently Ubuntu has started to ship with netplan. It required yaml configs to setup network interfaces. So for example it requires the following yaml to setup WiFi:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    wifis:
        interface_name:
            access-points:
                "apn":
                    password: "pwd"
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8]
            dhcp4: true
```

Notice under access-points, the network_ssid_name (apn) and the value of the password field (pwd) are in double quotes.

I looked around on stack overflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724331/python-dump-yaml-using-double-quotes-around-strings)

However this solution requires installing a module from pip call ruamel.yaml. I want to achieve this using the PyYAML module that is already available in my python distribution.

Here are some things I have tries so far:

```
import yaml

d = {'network': {'version': 2, 'renderer': 'NetworkManager', 'wifis':{'wlp58s0': {'access-points': {b'apn': {'password': b'pwd'}}}}}}


with open('/home/edyza/result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False, default_style=None)
```

The output of this is

```
network:
  renderer: NetworkManager
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      access-points:
        apn:
          password: pwd
```

Now I tried using escape characters and a few other things like

```
import yaml

d = {'network': {'version': 2, 'renderer': 'NetworkManager', 'wifis':{'wlp58s0': {'"access-points"': {'apn': {'password': "\"pwd\""}}}}}}

with open('/home/edyza/result.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(d, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False, default_style=None)
```

Then the output changes to

```
network:
  renderer: NetworkManager
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      '"access-points"':
        apn:
          password: '"pwd"'
```

What changes can I make to achieve the desired output with double quotes at appropriate key and values without using a third party module?

Or is there another approach I should consider to generate the yaml files.

Comment: I am pretty sure no YAML module is shipped with Python 2.7 or 3.x, neither `ruamel.yaml`, nor  PyYAML or PySyck (both of which only support versions of YAML that were outdated a decade or more ago). Please provide references (e.g. in the Python repository) to what would be *the yaml module that is shipped default with python`, so we know what you are referring to.

Comment: @Anthon you are correct. I just did an "import yaml" and assumed that yaml is shipped default with python. That is not correct. I will update the question to reflect that. I am using PyYAML.

Answer (score 0):

In YAML, quoting strings is not necessary except for special cases (if the string starts with a special character, if it contains control characters or `:<SPACE>`).

For a reference, may I recommend my [article on YAML quoting](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html)?

I think it is unlikely that the netplan YAML parser is really requiring those quotes.
Have you tried it without quotes and did you get an error?