# How can I add double quotes to items in a Python YAML dump without ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, python-3.8

I am generating a configuration file for a service that expects a list of double quoted string options. I want to avoid installing additional packages via `pip3 -r requirements.txt` as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726380/8900442) and use the `yaml` module that came available with `python 3.8.10` on `ubuntu 20.04`. I would like a way to solve this problem without searching for the lines and replacing them.

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py'
```

`python3 test.yaml`

```
import yaml

configDict = {}
configDict["OptionList"] = [
        "\"item1/Enable\"",
        "\"item2/Disable\""
    ]

with open('./testConfig.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(configDict, f)
```

`testConfig.yaml`

Current output:

```
OptionList:
- '"item1/Enable"'
- '"item2/Disable"'
```

Desired output:

```
OptionList:
- "item1/Enable"
- "item2/Disable"
```

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to load file as normal text, `replace("'", '"')` and save it back

Comment: Your "Desired output" **represents different data**, than "Current output". E.g. `"item1/Enable"` represents data `item1/Enable` which doesn't contain double quotes. But `'"item1/Enable"'` represents the data containing double quotes. A correct yaml dumper never emits an YAML file which represents the data different from input ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would need to digg in documentation and source code to see if it has option to change it.

At this moment I would simply get `text` and use `replace()`

```
import yaml

configDict = {
    "OptionList": [
        'item1/Enable',
        'item2/Disable'
    ]
}

text = yaml.dump(configDict)
print(text)

text = text.replace("'\"", '"').replace("\"'", '"')
print(text)

with open('./testConfig.yaml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Result:

```
OptionList:
- '"item1/Enable"'
- '"item2/Disable"'

OptionList:
- "item1/Enable"
- "item2/Disable"
```

---

If I use `default_style='"'` then I get all values in `" "`

```
import yaml

configDict = {
    "OptionList": [
        'item1/Enable',
        'item2/Disable'
    ]
}

text = yaml.dump(configDict, default_style='"')
print(text)
```

Result:

```
"OptionList":
- "item1/Enable"
- "item2/Disable"
```

Comment: I would have preferred a method not using `replace`, but this is elegant enough. Thank you!